# How to hide chart axes' labels

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I can't find out how to hide axes labels in Extjs4. Please, anybody?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:
What I need is to get rid of all labels on the x-axis (x values).

Comment: I've just added another field with empty string value into my data store, using this field as label of x-axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the axes property object use hidden: true.

```
{
    //title: 'Size',
    type: 'Numeric',
    position: 'left',
    hidden: true, // <------
    fields: ['sizeInBytes'],
    minimum: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, but it looks ugly

```
label: {
    renderer: function(name) {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short question, short answer: Just leave the `title` for the axis empty.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to be more specific. I don't mean `title`. What I need is to rid of all labels on the x-axis (x values).

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    //title: 'Size',
    type: 'Numeric',
    position: 'left',
    fields: ['sizeInBytes'],
    minimum: 0,
    label : {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is draw the main axis line but don't render the labels for each of the axis's steps right?

this seems to work for me:

```
{
  type : "Category",
  position : "bottom",
  fields : ["person"],
  title : "",
  hidden : false,
  drawLabel: function(){

      return null;
  }
}
```

-> See [drawLabel()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.chart.axis.Axis-method-drawLabel)